# Detect client's disconnection WebSocket

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, websocket

I'm using WebSocket & nodeJs. I can detect user's connection and present it, but I can't detect user's disconnetion. The method **on('close',function()....)** happens when I shut down the server and not when a user closes the tab or something. What can I do? I realy don't know how to do it right now. Thank you all! Hoping you'll help me.

Answer (score 2):

You should implement heartbeat requests (inside websocket connection) from client to server (every 20-30 sec) and limit connection to some period (40-50 sec) - this can be done in web server (or even load balancer settings).

When server find that there is no heartbeat request it means that this connection is broken - client closed tab or something.

**Updated**: oh! Seems socket.io have heartbeat implementation, so my answer was a bit common.

Answer (score 2):

To detect socket disconnection, I use this method which works fine :

```
socket.once('disconnect', function () {
    // socket is disconnected
});
```

Or

```
socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    // socket is disconnected
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Correct (and upvoted) answer but imho it's socket.on and not socket.once (link to the doc : https://socket.io/docs/#sending-and-receiving-events).

Comment: Oh okay, I think you can use both because I'm really using "socket.once" and it works properly :)

Comment: I want to get the username in this function. The username is saved on the session. How can I get it from this method?

Comment: If you are using express-session, you can share sessions with socket.io with this module : https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-socket.io-session

Answer (score 0):

```
io.sockets.on('connection',function(socket){
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    // Your stuff here
  });
});
```